# How to limit array to 5 items and put new item at top of list

Tags: reactjs

I want to print a list of scores with a limit of 5. The newest score at the top. The app is a simple timer which the user can hold down the button, release, then tap a Done! button to set the score in the state. Currently the scores printed on the app from scoreArray are duplicated multiple times exponentially when click the Done! button.

The code currently is what I've been advised to try but it doesn't work.

Setting the state with the score:

```
onSubmit() {

                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    scoreArray:[this.state.scoreArray.concat(ms(this.state.time,{verbose: true})), ...prevState.scoreArray],
                    time:0,
                    submit:true

                  }));
```

And in the render I have this:

```
{this.state.scoreArray.map(function(item,i){

          return (i < 5) ? <Text key={i}>{item}</Text> : null}).filter(x=>x)

          }
```

I expect the scores list to populate the newest score at the top, pushing the older scores down the list and these older scores disappear when the limit of the scores is > 5.

Comment: What about `this.state.scoreArray.slice(0, 5).map`...?

Comment: Try `scoreArray:[ms(this.state.time,{verbose: true}), ...prevState.scoreArray]`. Also, you should delete items as you're adding new ones so that it does not increase over time. What you are curretly doing is `new_array= old_array + score (at the end) + old_array`.

Comment: When you say newest do you mean newest added or is there another way to determine what's newest?

Comment: Yes, by "new" I meant the last one that was added.

Comment: @F.G. - that's it! Brilliant. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are again providing an array inside the "scoreArray", hence the nested structure. Try changing the setState call to this: 
`

```
 this.setState(prevState => ({
                    scoreArray:[ms(this.state.time,{verbose: true}), ...prevState.scoreArray],
                    time:0,
                    submit:true

                  }));
```

`

This way you are adding a new element on top of your array and then spreading the previous elements in the new array.